# Jquery library/toggle

Tags: jquery, user-interface, toggle

I'm using this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/3951/) for a toggle and hide menu but can't get it working, think it has something to do with the libraries?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
/** Style for the body **/
 body {
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
/** Style for the button & div **/
 .myButton {
    padding: .2em 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.mySelect {
    padding: .2em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    display:none;
}
#myDiv {
    color:Green;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:2px solid #333;
    display:none;
    text-align:justify;
}
#myDiv p {
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 0.917em;
}
/** Style for the cointainer **/
 #body {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 534px;
}
html, body {
    background-color:White;
}
hr {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body">


    <p>
        <select class="mySelect"> 
            <option value="left">Left</option> 
            <option value="right">Right</option>

            <option value="up">Up</option>
            <option value="down">Down</option>
        </select>
        <button id="button" class="myButton">Run Effect</button>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
 $(function() {
$(".myButton").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: $('.mySelect').val() };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;

    $('#myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is to use for a menu that will slide in from the left when reduced to a mobile site..I've been at this for hours and think ive narrowed it down to the problem being the libraries

it says on [the](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/3951/) JSFiddle to use jquery 2.0.2 and UI 1.10.3 but I'm unsure of how to link them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to include jQuery.js before any plugins or dependent code.

jQueryUI extends jQuery with plugin functions therefore you need to switch the loading order

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[full page demo with your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/mgNoE7hrcLODfvdaCViZ)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

First add the **jquery.min.js** and then add **jquery-ui.min.js**